# Убрать прелоадер когда загрузились указанные секции?

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка

Использую `Preloader` для сайта, он убирается когда выполняется следующая функция

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
  var preloader = $('.preloader');
  $(preloader).delay(300).fadeOut('slow');
  $('body').addClass('loaded');
});
```

Но как показывается практика такой вариант не подходит. Слишком много висит прелоадер ибо ждет пока загрузится весь весь сайт(а он достаточно большой). А если вместо `load` использовать `DOMContentLoaded` - сайт слишком быстро показывается. Можно ли функцию `load` использовать к примеру лишь для двух секции. Когда загрузился бы `header+` секция `home` — показывать сайт?

Comment: Вижу лоадер, интуитивно 2 сек, закрываю, следующий... Если по делу, то нужно знать хоть приблизительное HTML содержимое этих двух секций, возможно, что просто нужно выделить стили, скрипты и поместить в тег `head`, вынеся из внешнего файла, для отрисовки первичного экрана и скрывать лоадер по DOMContentLoaded или тому же `$(document).ready`.

Comment: если принять, что загруженная секция - это секция, в которой подгружен html, картинки и скрипты, то вам надо 1. дождаться $(document).ready, 2. дождаться загрузки картинок внутри указанной секции ($('img').load()) 3. дождаться загрузки скриптов (не знаю как, но, наверно, этот пункт можно опустить =) )

Comment: Ajax? Разбиение загрузки на части?)